# MongoDB schema design for one model with a different templates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I just want to have your opinion guys, because I'm having a hard time thinking whether this schema design is good. So before I ask, here's one of the function of the website I'm building:

1. User can post something on what they're selling
2. User can search the posts
3. Users view the post and it's specific details

Here's my POST Schema

```
var PostSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    maincategory: String,
    subcategory: String,
    quantity: String,
    name: String,
    description: String,
    plusdetails: {}
}, {strict: false});
```

On the website, when you post something, you will select the main category and it's sub-category, for example I'm selling a Computer, on my PostSchema, it accepts the fields like maincategory, subcategory, quantity, name and description. Then since you selected a subcategory for computers, I have a specific template to serve specific details for Computer (like GPU, CPU, how many cores, how much ram and etc..) So that's why I have this called plusdetails on my PostSchema, that accepts a schemaless design.

And if for example I want to sell a Cellphone, then on my plusdetails, it will contain (like OS, how much ram, its CPU, Camera Pixel and etc..)
Here's a preview of what it looks like (sorry this is not about cellphone or computer, but you'll get the idea)

[image][image]

So all in all, every different categories, when you post, they're all using one model which is PostSchema even though they contain different values (which is on the plusdetails). So when I search on the posts, I'll just use

```
Post.find({query: data})
```

because they're all residing on one model.

Now my question is, is this the right way to do this?

Because at first, what I was thinking to do is in every category is equivalent to one model like for example,

- PostCarSchema
- PostComputerSchema
- PostHouseSchema

and so on and so forth, it will take hundreds of models. With this, I can define their schema properly, I have a full control on what it should be there. But the problem is, when the User search something. What model would I use?

Because it's just a one search bar, for example, I'll search "Lenovo",

[image]

On this approach (which is one category = one model), how will I search lenovo if I have multiple models. Because lenovo can be a computer or a mobile phone. It's because of this problem I didn't do this approach. Before i could just use `Post.find({query: data})` but with this, I can't because there's hundreds of models.

So how can I design my mongodb schema that can serve POST items that each of their own has a specific template? Is it alright the one that I did? or is there a better way?

Comment: Look at [Discriminators](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/discriminators.html)

Comment: Thanks! i'll check it out